# Jenkins pipeline: skip interactive input step when triggered by cron?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins scripted pipeline which requests interactive input at the start e.g:

```groovy
def options = input message: 'Select options', parameters: [...]
```

However I now wish to also run this job on a schedule using a cron trigger.

How should I make it skip the `input` step only when the job has been automatically triggered on a timer, whilst retaining the ability to choose the parameters manually when triggered manually?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a built-in way to get `input` to return its defaults in this case, however you can do it manually as follows:

```groovy
def options = [:]

// If there are any TimerTriggerCause then this build was started by a cron timer
if (currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger$TimerTriggerCause')) {
    // Options to default to when running automatically on a schedule
    options = [
        FOO: 'foo default could be different for auto-scheduled runs',
        BAR: true,
    ]
} else {
    // Interactive option selection
    options = input message: 'Select options',
        parameters: [
                string(name: 'FOO', defaultValue: 'foo default for interactive selection input', trim: true, description '...'),
                booleanParam(name: 'BAR', defaultValue: true, description: '...'),
        ]
}

echo "Chosen: ${options.toString()}"

if (options.BAR) {
    // do something based on `options.FOO`
}
```

Unfortunately you have to manually keep the 2 if blocks 'in sync' in terms of added/modified/removed parameters such that `options` ends up with a consistent set of keys in either case.